# Ruby connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I want to use [open source code](http://geeqe.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/scripts/load.rb) to get Stack Overflow data into my MySQL database:

```
if ARGV.size != 5
  puts "Usage load.rb Usage load.rb <XML file path> <db host> <db user> <db pass> <db name>"
  exit 1
end

my = Mysql::new(ARGV[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3], ARGV[4])

puts "Loading badges"

parser = XML::SaxParser.file(ARGV[0] + '/badges.xml')
parser.callbacks = BadgeCallbacks.new(my)
parser.parse
```

I am getting the following error:

```
load.rb:129:in `new': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql::Error)
    from load.rb:129:in `<main>'
mac@localhost:[~/rubycode]$ruby load.rb '~/rubycode/stackoverflow_1' 'localhost' 'test' 'test' 'stackflow'
load.rb:129:in `new': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql::Error)
    from load.rb:129:in `<main>'
```

I do have MySQL gems installed using RVM.

Comment: Is MySQL running? what is the output of `ps aux | grep -i mysql`?

Comment: yes mysql is running I can connect using mysql command and padde i also did you command and got the following

mac@localhost:[~/rubycode]$ps aux | grep -i mysql
mac     20789   1.2  0.0  2435116    524 s001  S+    4:45PM   0:00.01 grep -i mysql
_mysql   54530   0.0  0.6  2662668  47920   ??  S    Sat12PM   
I do have more output but you get the idea that mysql is up

Comment: What's the output of which mysql? Do you have a /etc/my.cnf and if so what are the contents of the client section. Specifically you'd be looking for the line with socket = /path/to/a/socket

Comment: $which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql I am on a mac